# add smooth behavior on scrollBehavior savedPosition in VueRouter

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Im adding the scrollBehavior in vueRouter and I can't find anywhere how can I add the behavior: smooth on the savedPosition in a timeout?
here is my code where I would like to add the smooth option :

```js
  scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
    if (savedPosition) {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve(savedPosition);
        }, 1000);
      });
    }
  },
```

Thank you alot in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
    scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
      if (savedPosition) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            savedPosition.behavior = "smooth"
            resolve(savedPosition);
        }, 1000);
      });
    }
  },
```

Comment: Late answer but thank you very much for your help sir !